# Package on pipx is missing a version

Tags: python, conda, pipx

I'm new to Python, so I'm probably missing something about pipx, but I've been instructed to install version 0.0.13 and the latest version I'm seeing is 0.0.8:

```bash
pipx install insanely-fast-whisper==0.0.13 --force
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    /Users/jacksteam/Library/Logs/pipx/cmd_2024-02-16_17.30.08_pip_errors.log

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.0.10 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8; 0.0.11 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8; 0.0.12 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8; 0.0.13 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8; 0.0.9 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement insanely-fast-whisper==0.0.13 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3, 0.0.4, 0.0.5b0, 0.0.5b1, 0.0.5b2, 0.0.5b3, 0.0.5, 0.0.6, 0.0.7, 0.0.8)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for insanely-fast-whisper==0.0.13

Error installing insanely-fast-whisper from spec 'insanely-fast-whisper==0.0.13'.
```

I'm using Conda with Python 3.10. I installed pipx with Homebrew as suggested in the pipx docs.

Answer (score 0):

The key line in the error is:

```bash
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 
    0.0.10 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8; 
    0.0.11 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8; 
    0.0.12 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8; 
    0.0.13 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8; 
    0.0.9 Requires-Python <=3.11,>=3.8
```

I was using Conda for a Python env, but Homebrew to install pipx. It looks like Pipx was confused over the Python version.

After I removed the Homebrew pipx, this worked:

```bash
conda create -n whisper-310 python=3.10
conda activate whisper-310
pip install pipx
pipx install insanely-fast-whisper==0.0.13
```

If you see 0.0.8 is the latest version, make sure pipx was installed under the correct Python version.